# Enable Developer Mode Extension For Chrome Browser using cmd

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cmd

i have searched a lot, and then came here to ask. Is it possible to start chrome browser in enabled developers mode for extensions using cmd ?

I tried few flags from  http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no flag to enable developer mode. But you can force developer mode to be enabled *for new Chrome profiles* by setting `extensions.ui.developer_mode` to `true` in the master preference file.

On Linux and Windows, this file is called `master_preferences` and stored next to the Chrome executable. For an example of such a file, see https://github.com/Rob--W/extension-dev-tools/tree/master/chrome

On Mac, the location of the master preference files is [a bit more complicated](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/mac/master_prefs.mm). Chrome attempts to find the file in the user directory, and if it's not found, then the system-wide directory is used. And master preferences are not supported for `Canary` on Mac.

Google Chrome builds (stable, beta, dev):

- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Google Chrome Master Preferences`
- `/Library/Google/Google Chrome Master Preferences`

Chromium:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/Chromium Master Preferences`
- `/Library/Application Support/Chromium/Chromium Master Preferences`